# ArcGIS Online custom pop-up attributes displayed by a query

Tags: arcgis-online, query, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder

While using ESRIs ArcOnline I am building a web application with multiple custom pop-ups. When I click on a building I want to provide the exact zoning code information with a link to the appropriate website full of zoning codes.

All of the zoning information (along with its appropriate links) has been loaded into fields of the building attribute table. I fully understand how the pop-ups work, but I was wondering if there was anyway possible to change what is displayed on the pop-up through a query.

**--> CURRENT pop-up display**

[image]

**--> QUERY purpose**: the queries purpose would be to change the pop-up display so if "Historic Area?" is "Yes" then the link is displayed. If the answer is "No" then no link is displayed.

[image]

In conclusion, I simply want to make the pop-up cleaner, removing "If yes - more info: " and an unnecessary broken link accompanied if the answer is "No".

So is this at all a possible task?

Comment: not through AGOL itself if you dev your own custom app you can do what you want. (90% sure of that statement)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able now using Arcade. I have not tried this myself, but have a look at the second half of this blog, where they show one string if a condition is true and a different string if the condition is false: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2018/01/08/add-color-to-pop-ups/